# copying api source into project in android

Tags: java, android, shareactionprovider

I am trying to modify the behavior of ShareActionProvider in android such that it does not show history. In this process i need to copy source code of ShareActionProvider, ActivityChooserModel and ActivityChooserView into my android eclipse project. I am facing resolve issues like eclipse is not able to resolve R.attr.actionModeShareDrawable, ActivityChooserModel, ActivityChooserView. This is happening in all the classes which i have copies from api source.
Is there are way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to copy the values from `attrs.xml` from the android source code

Comment: Yes, i tried searching for that initially but I cant find it in android-17.

Comment: adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\values - this is where it is for me, i don't have the 17 resources so i don't know if its there (i guess it is..)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found it finally. But its a nightmare to selectively choose which resources have been referenced in the Java source. I guess copying all the resources is not the only solution. Any intelligent way of doing it?

Comment: defining it in attrs is just for use it with xml, if you initialize this class with code i think you can just remove the attrs from the source code and define everything manually